# how to remove quoted words/phrases from a string using python?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string that contains words or phrases that are enclosed in double quotes and I need to remove them from quotes., in python. Example:

**The text has "single quotes" and "commas".**

**The text has "double quotes".**

removing the words from the quotes results in this:

**The text has " " and " ".**

**The text has " ".**

I used the RE `re.finditer` that lists all the quotes found, but I know how it would be to remove the words that exist between the quotes in the string. Anybody know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>> from re import sub 
>> s 
'The text has "single quotes" and "commas".' 
>> sub('".*?"', '" "',s)
'The text has " " and " ".'
```

Comment: Addition: .* matches "none or more characters". So ".*" will match an empty pair of quotes (" "). ".+" matches "one or more characters", so will not match empty quotes,

Answer (score 1):

A bit complicated, but maybe,

```
(?<=")[^\s".][^"\r\n]*|[^"\r\n]*[^\s".](?=")
```

might be OK to look into.

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BC1kuM/1/)

---

This pattern would probably fail on some edge cases, which you'd likely want to look into:

```
[^\s".]
```

#### Test

```
import re

string = '''
The text has "single quotes" and "commas".
The text has "double quotes"
"single quotes" and "commas"
"double quotes"
"d"
"d""d""d""d"

'''

expression = r'(?<=")[^\s".][^"\r\n]*|[^"\r\n]*[^\s".](?=")'

print(re.sub(expression, '', string))
```

#### Output

```
The text has "" and "".
The text has ""
"" and ""
""
""
""""""""
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/BC1kuM/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/BC1kuM/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this simple regex:

```
"[\w\s]+"
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/k71Ikb/2)

We capture any word characters and possible spaces between `" "`, and then replace with `""`:

```
expression = r'"[\w\s]+"'
print(re.sub(expression, '""', string))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code. Hope it helps.

```
text = 'The text has "single quotes" and "commas".'
text = re.sub('"[^"]*[$"]', '""', text)
print(text)  # The text has "" and "".
```